# Não consigo efetuar as operações indicadas

Tags: java

> Elabore um programa que, dado 2 vetores inteiros de 20 posições, efetue as respectivas operações indicadas por um terceiro vetor de caracteres de 20 posições também fornecido pelo usuário, contendo as quatro operações aritméticas em qualquer combinação, armazenando os resultados num quarto vetor.

```
public class Funcao {

    int v1[] = new int [20];
    int v2[] = new int [20];
    String oper [] = new String[20];
    double result [] = new double [20];


int i;
for (i=0;i<20;i++){
v1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite "+(i+1)+" operando"));
oper[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite "+(i+1)+" operador(+,-,*,/)");
v2[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite "+(i+1)+" operando"));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        switch(oper[i]){
            case "+":
                result[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
                break;
            case "-":
                result[i] = v1[i] - v2[i];
                break;
            case "*":
                result[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
                break;
            case "/":
                result[i] = v1[i] / v2[i];
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Operador inválido");
        }
    }
```